# Parse Errors in pod files in iOS Push Notification app in xcode 6.1.1

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging, appium-ios

I am developing a push notification app for iOS in xcode 6.1.1. 
I am using cocoapods and Firebase Cloud Messaging in Objective-C. 
I have Performed all the steps properly but on compiling the project I get lot of parse issues in pod files(pod files like GPBCodedInputStream.h, GPBArray.h, GPBDictionary.h,etc). 
What is the solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

for Firebase Cloud Messaging prerequisites, you need a few things set up in your environment:

- **Xcode 7.0 or later**
- **An Xcode project targeting iOS 7 or above**
- **The bundle identifier of your app**
- **CocoaPods 1.0.0 or later**

Comment: So should I update XCode? But I have mac os 10.9.5. I think XCode 7 is not supported in  MAC OS 10.9.5.  What can be the possible solution??

Comment: @user3444096 **Firebase Cloud Messaging** required Xcode 7 or later. **Xcode** **7** requires a Mac running OS X version 10.10.4 or later. So, you need to update your Mac OS X too.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But will updating MAC OS lead to other problems like changes in the settings/environment variables? Also I am having Appium on my MAC. So will updating MAC OS affect the working of Appium?? Because I need Appium Working and I cant take risk. And it is a big leap from MAC OS 10.9.5 to 10.12

Comment: You are welcome! Regarding **Appium**, I don't know anything. You have to check with that and do the necessary things.